# How to have a Command(able) view or a Button with content in MAUI?

Tags: binding, maui

I need a composite clickable MAUI component on which I can bind a command.

- `Button`s can't contain content, only text.
- `ContentView`s don't have Command so I tried this way

//

```
public partial class BtnView : BaseContentView<BtnVm>
{
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    public object CommandParameter { get; set; }

    public BtnView() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static BindableProperty CommandProperty { get; set; } = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(Command), typeof(BtnView));
    public static BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty { get; set; } = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CommandParameter), typeof(object), typeof(BtnView));
}
```

This way, I hoped Command property to be bindable but:

- I get an XFC0009 error when binding a Command

> No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Command", or mismatching type between value and property.

- There's no mechanism to fire it by clicking.

How am I meant to implement this kind of component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Xamarin Forms, Maui can [attach a `TapGestureRecognizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) to any visual element. See also [`TapGestureRecognizer` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.tapgesturerecognizer?view=xamarin-forms).

Add this to the `ContentView` in xaml:

```
<ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
        Tapped="OnTapped">
    </TapGestureRecognizer>
</ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
```

Add this to the "code behind" in xaml.cs:

```
protected void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

Comment: I need to reference a command from a parent component so I'll use `<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectChild}" CommandParameter="{Binding Child}"/>`